# What is address sanitization in C?

Tags: c, sanitization

Sanitization keeps code clean, removing the "dirty" injections. In HTML and JavaScript, this is accomplished by removing unsafe tags or escaping user input.

What does "sanitization" mean to C?

Comment: Have you tried *searching* for the term? What did you find then? What problems do you have with what you found?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yeah, I tried searching, I try to be respectful of the community here. On google, I found results related to HTML and JavaScript, but nothing about C that I could understand. I'm familiar with Java, so I just assumed that stuff like referencing out of bounds memory would cause my program to crash. I didn't realize how much I was taking for granted. That you can compile stuff like a[5] and 5[a] in C, or attacks by `stack smashing` or `row hammering` are all news to me. There're a lot of fundamentals I realize I'm missing by starting to learn the answer to my question

Comment: Don't just search for "sanitazion" but *"address sanitazion"* specificallu, probably with a *C* added.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Googling `address sanitization in C` didn't yield any resources I understood. In fact, the two links that people responded to this question with were the first 2 things I saw when googling. But I didn't get why we needed those tools, I didn't get the theory behind them, until I found a link talking about how potentially harmful illegal memory accesses are. I've never seen their security downside, because as a java user, there simply IS no security downside, your program just stops.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think this is funny... but if I google `address sanitization C`, a link to this question is the first link that pops up. I don't think that I knew enough about address sanitization to ask a proper question when I asked this, though, so I got shot down. (I suppose what I should have asked is "Why do we need to use address sanitization in C", which has an easy answer: "they can cause vulnerabilities".

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Have you tried searching for the term? If you've found any good resources that I've missed, I'd be interested.

Comment: The very first link I got was [to the Wikipedia article on AddressSanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer). It should be a pretty good start IMO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a compiler feature (at least in Clang) that tries to detect memory addresses that are invalid, such as those that are out-of-bounds, or that are still being used after they are freed.

You can enable it with the `-fsanitize=address` compiler flag. See [here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search led me here:
https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer

If this is what is meant by sanitization, it's just a set of compile-time address safety checks.